# Avoid infite loop while message consume

Tags: java, multithreading, infinite-loop

Hi I have the following code :

```
public abstract class MyConsumer<T extends IMessage, S extends ISubscriptionEnum>
    implements IBatchConsumer<T> {

    @Override
    public void run() {   
        
        while (true) {
            if(active){
                try{
                    // some condition
                    consume();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Sleep was interrupted: " + e);
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

This is throwing a sonar issue with infinite loop. But this consume() is deliberately kept in infinite loop to continue mesage consumption. How to avoid the infinite loop error in this scenario ?

**UPDATE:**

Thinking of keeping the condition as below, but will this server my purpose of the infinite loop ?

```
while(active){
    try{
        consume();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Sleep was interrupted: " + e);
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a way to stop it, and then do `while(shouldRun)` instead.

Comment: do you have any possibility to use wait/notify builtin methods against some monitor here? the classic way

Comment: @marstran : I have updated the question after your suggestion. You ,meant a way like this. Can u pls see and respond..

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov : yes I can use sleep wait etc.

Comment: If your code is correct, then SonarCube is wrong.  Reconfigure (or ditch entirely) SonarCube.

Comment: @iggy : This is a running code. Can u please check my UPDATE. Is it okay like this.

Comment: I don't see the point of your calls to "interrupt", though.  It looks to me that if consume() fails for any reason, you set the interrupted state, which causes the subsequent sleep() to imediately fail, which sets the interrupted state,  By definition, a thread calling interrupt on itself is not in any wait state that is interruptible,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insetead of using while (true) , you should check if the thread has been stopped or paused.

```
private volatile boolean isStopped = false;

 public void run(){
   while(!isStopped ){
      try{
     // keep doing your logic
     }catch(){
       isStopped = true; // do this only if you want to stop. 
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();// This line does not ensure thread to stop.
       
     }
   }
 }
```

So, you can use the flag isStopped  to stop the processing of the tread. Sonar configuration is correct, it will keep complaining about such error. You need to change code.